# Escape whitespace in paths using nautilus script

Tags: python, nautilus

I didn't think this would be as tricky as it turned out to be, but here I am. I'm trying to write a Nautilus script in Python to upload one or more images to Imgur just by selecting and right clicking them. It works well enough with both single images and multiple images - as long as they don't contain any whitespace. In fact, you can upload a single image containing whitespace, just not multiple ones.

The problem is that NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS returns all the selected files and directories as a space separated string. So for example, it could look like this:

```
print os.environment['NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS']
/home/nevon/Desktop/test image.png /home/nevon/Desktop/test.jpg
```

What I need is a way to -either in bash or Python- escape the spaces in the path - but not the spaces that delimit different items. Either that, or a way to put quotation marks around each item.

The ultimate solution would be if I could do that in bash and then send the items as separate arguments to my python script. Something like:

```
python uploader.py /home/nevon/Desktop/test\ image.png /home/nevon/Desktop/test.jpg
```

I've tried RTFM'ing, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of good solutions for this. At least not that I've found. Any ideas?

Comment: `python uploader.py '...test image.png' ...` but this belongs on superuser.com

Comment: or `mv 'test image.png' test-image.png`. Yes, you can use spaces in filenames, but nobody said it would be fun in all circumstances.

Comment: I know that you can quote the arguments to allow for spaces, but how would I do that when $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS just feeds me a space delimited list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` should be newline delimited, not space delimited.  In that case, the following should work from bash:

```
echo -e $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | xargs python uploader.py
```

Comment: That's what I've read too, but here's the output I get from echo -e $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS > output

/home/nevon/Desktop/test image.png /home/nevon/Desktop/test.gif

Comment: Eh, I guess the comments don't allow for paragraphs. Anyway, despite what the docs say, it's a space delimited list. Your suggestion didn't work, sadly.

Comment: I'm flagging this as correct. At first it didn't work, but now suddenly it does. I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time, but it works now. I did have to do: echo -e  $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | xargs --delimiter="\n" python uploader.py
But now it works!

Comment: you've got to admire the bravery of using an answer while having no idea how it works, kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Skipping one level of evaluation shows that the nautilus documentation is incomplete and that there is a better way much less subject to who-knows-how-many levels of interpretation. Nautilus passes selected files as script arguments:

```
$ cat ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/arguments.sh
#!/bin/sh
rm -f /tmp/arguments.*
outf=/tmp/arguments.$$
echo "$0: $#" > $outf
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    echo "$1"
     if [ ! -r $1 ] ; then echo "cwd is not correct"; fi
    shift
done >> $outf
echo paths $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS >> $outf
for i in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS ; do
    echo "+$i+"
done >> $outf
```

I sent the output to `/tmp` since I didn't want to hunt for the stdout. Given:

```
$ ls -1
a
b
c with space
d
e with space
g
```

Select all the files in the directory and Scripts->arguments.sh yields:

```
$ cat /tmp/arguments.20447 
/home/msw/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/arguments.sh: 6
a
b
c with space
d
e with space
g
paths /home/msw/junk/a /home/msw/junk/b /home/msw/junk/c with space 
  /home/msw/junk/d /home/msw/junk/e with space 
  /home/msw/junk/g
+/home/msw/junk/a+
+/home/msw/junk/b+
+/home/msw/junk/c+
+with+
+space+
+/home/msw/junk/d+
+/home/msw/junk/e+
+with+
+space+
+/home/msw/junk/g+
```

Could I have quoted `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` to avoid this? Sure. I didn't to demonstrate that how many levels of interpolation with the variable is questionable, but `argv` stays unmolested.

Use argv (or `sys.argv` in Python) and save some headache. Also the documented semantics of the environment [variables is weird](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/unstable/gosnautilus-444.html.en).

Comment: Thanks, `"$1"` in bash worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this as I'm at a Windows machine, but have you tried using $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_URIS instead?  Then, in python you could get the paths with something like:

```
[f.strip() for f in os.environment['NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_URIS'].split('file://') if len(f) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, `echo` sometimes turns newlines in variables into spaces. The following should work:

```
echo -e "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | xargs python uploader.py
```