# Working with UTF-characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to create a script that walks a directory and renames files. I would like to be able to extract the filename and file extension separately, but if the file path contains either spaces or Swedish UTF8-characters such as ÅÄÖ, it breakes.

I've found the below shown snippet to extract the filename + extension here on SO, but as I am seeing that it works on paths with no UTF-chars or whitespace, I am thinking that I am not properly escaping my variables.

Perhaps I am doing something wrong. Any ideas on what I can do to make this work with paths with UTF8 chars and whitespace?

```
for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do

  FULLPATH="$file"
  FILENAME=${FULLPATH##*/}
  FILEEXTENSION=${FILENAME##*.}
  BASEDIRECTORY=${FULLPATH%$FILENAME}

  #Log the vars for debugging
  echo "$FULLPATH" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
  echo "$FILENAME" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
  echo "$FILEEXTENSION" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
  echo "$BASEDIRECTORY" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt

done
```

Comment: The snippet you posted is fine, but there is no way `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` can contain multiple paths, some of them quoted. Is there a way to avoid this variable?

Comment: ... Well, not quite impossible, of course, but most likely the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATH variable is [new-line escaped per item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980250/escape-whitespace-in-paths-using-nautilus-script).

You need to use:

```
while read file; do

  FULLPATH="$file"
  FILENAME=${FULLPATH##*/}
  FILEEXTENSION=${FILENAME##*.}
  BASEDIRECTORY=${FULLPATH%$FILENAME}

  #Log the vars for debugging
  echo "$FULLPATH" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
  echo "$FILENAME" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
  echo "$FILEEXTENSION" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt
  echo "$BASEDIRECTORY" >> ~/Desktop/log.txt

done <<<"$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
```

Comment: +1 I didn't go so far as to read up on NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATH before commenting ...

Answer (score 0):

I have this in [my dotfiles](http://mths.be/dotfiles):

```
# Prefer US English and use UTF-8
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG="en_US"
```

With that configuration, it seems to work:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 Mathias  staff  68 Jan 17 11:32 test space test
drwxr-xr-x  2 Mathias  staff  68 Jan 17 11:29 test©test
$ for file in *; do echo "$file"; done
test space test
test©test
```